# MongoDB $gt not working

Tags: mongodb

Below query gives me no results, though there are fields matching the geo location and time stamp.

I have tried changing the `$gt` to `$ne` and it returns the sum of all `$value`s.

I have even tried checking `timeStamp` greater than 0. still no result. Here timestamp is a double datatype.

```
db.csv2.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        $and: [{
            loc: {
                $geoWithin: {
                    $box: [
                        [-128.232422, 26.382028],
                        [-109.6875, 43.624147]
                    ]
                }
            }
        }, {
            timeStamp: {
                $gt: 1432201420790
            }
        }]
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        total: {
            $sum: "$value"
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Do the fields match BOTH `loc` *and* `timeStamp`, not just one or the other? Can you match `timestamp` *without* specifying `loc`? You do not require `$and` here; simply `$match: { loc: {...}, timeStamp: {...} }` will do the trick.

Comment: By match, Do u mean if the condition matches. If so, yes.. loc with the given coordinates and time stamp greater than that range has results. 

I tried running it with out $and and it throws me a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

The error given to you is explicit. Read the doc to see how to implement the $gt aggregation function : [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gt/)

Basically, the condition is an array

```
{ $gt: ["$timeStamp", 1432201420790] }
```

**[EDIT]**
Your issue probably comes from the syntax with the dollar sign before the timestamp field which is missing in your code. Try this

```
{ $gt: ["$timeStamp", 1432201420790] }
```

instead of

```
{ timeStamp: { $gt: 1432201420790 }}
```

Comment: Note that the syntax of `$gt` operator for regular and aggregation queries is different.

Comment: I have done quite some amount of research. Still not able to fix it. My basic need is to match 2 conditions and group the result to do sum operation.

Out of the 2 condition one is it check if a particular field is greater than a given number. How can i do it.. :(

Comment: Could you post a sample of your documents ? I'll try on my side

Comment: just saw this on another post, $gt (the normal one) seems to work only on integers whereas the aggregation one is different i guess, any confirmations about this behavior?